# How to Provide Fluent Validation on Multi-Select Component using MudBlazor

Tags: c#, blazor, fluentvalidation, mudblazor

I have a Blazor app that manages a lot of form input. Every form is tied to an instance of type IncidentLog, and every UI element of the form is tied to a property of that IncidentLog instance.

In the form, we have a MudSelect component where T="Department". The MudSelect has MultiSelection="true", and the results are stored in a IEnumerable(Department) Departments property of the IncidentLog instance.

This component works totally fine, but I've tried implementing FluentValidation in the form and I'm not sure how to define the expression of the For  parameter of this MudSelect component. It looks like it's expecting me to pass an object that matches T="Department", but the validation I need to run against the validator is based off of IEnumerable(Department)... I just want to check that the user has selected at least one department from the multiselect component.

**Error message when trying to pass IEnumerable object to the For validator:**
[image]

**IncidentLogPropertiesComponent razor page - relevant blurb**

```
<MudForm Model="@Log" @ref="@form" Validation="@(incidentLogValidator.ValidateValue)" ValidationDelay="100">

<MudCardContent Class="pt-0">

...
        
        <MudSelect T="Department" ToStringFunc="@ConverterDepartment" Dense="true" Margin="Margin.Dense" Label="Affected Departments:" MultiSelection="true" @bind-SelectedValues="Log.Departments" Clearable>
            @foreach (var department in Departments.OrderBy(o=>o.DepartmentName).ToList())
            {
                <MudSelectItem  Value="@department"/>
            }
        </MudSelect>

...
</MudCardContent>
</MudForm>
```

**IncidentLog.cs:**

```
public class IncidentLog : Log
{
    [Key]
    public int IncidentID { get; set; }
    
    ....
    [Write(false)]
    public IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set; } = new HashSet<Department>();//3
    ....
}
```

**IncidentLogPropertiesComponentBase**

```
public class IncidentLogPropertiesComponentBase : OwningComponentBase<iIncidentLogRepository>, IDisposable
{
    protected IncidentLogValidator incidentLogValidator = new IncidentLogValidator();
    ...
    [Parameter]
    public IncidentLog? Log
    {
        get
        {
            return (AppState.SelectedLog != null && AppState.SelectedLog.LogType.LogTypeID == 2) ? (IncidentLog)AppState.SelectedLog : null;
        }
        set
        {
            AppState.SetLog(value);
        }
    }
 
}
```

**IncidentLogValidator:**

```
public class IncidentLogValidator: AbstractValidator<IncidentLog>
{
    public IncidentLogValidator()
    {
        ...
        RuleFor(t => t.Departments).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Must enter at least one department affected.");
    }

    public Func<object, string, Task<IEnumerable<string>>> ValidateValue => async (model, propertyName) =>
    {
        var result = await ValidateAsync(ValidationContext<IncidentLog>.CreateWithOptions((IncidentLog)model, x => x.IncludeProperties(propertyName)));
        if (result.IsValid)
            return Array.Empty<string>();
        return result.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
    };
}
```

*I didn't link my AppState state management file even though it's referenced in code above - I don't think it's relevant to the issue I'm having.

How do I provide Fluent Validation to Multi-Select Dropdowns using MudBlazor?